# Use Zero Subtotal method use on order greater than 0

Tags: magento-1.9, zero-subtotal

I'm trying to make quote system, so the customer can place order as quote without paying, 
The checkout also have other payment options.
I used a little hack to show "Zero Subtotal Checkout" option on magento onepage checkout payment methods section. by editing below file

so it shows payment option when order greater than 3000

```
/app/code/local/Mage/Payment/Model/Method/Free.php

public function isAvailable($quote = null)
    {
        return parent::isAvailable($quote) && !empty($quote) && Mage::app()->getStore()->roundPrice($quote->getGrandTotal()) > 3000;
    }
```

But when i select that it automatically deselecting and hide itself.

can someone help me to fix this issue please